# Access: Update and Append in same form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

I am new to using the front end tools/VBA in access, but I am an advanced programmer.

I have a situation where I need to record the date, and method of commute, for a particular individual on a monthly basis. What I have done so far is  programatically create a form that lists every day of the month and has a blank space next to it for the user to enter in how he commuted.  User only has to fill in if he/she clean commuted. The question is, how do I:

```
1. Select Records that have already been entered for a month and populate them to a line on my form.
2. Show a blank space for a user to enter info on any date that is not associated with a record.
3. Update any records they changed.
4. Append any new records they enter in the blanks.
```

I need to do this all on one form so it is easy.  I cannot ask the users to navigate.

I appreciate any suggestion that might lead me to a solution.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing and working (strange not find examples of this), I have determined the way to do this.

1. Do not programmatically create the form.

   a. Forms in Access are tied so closely to accesses "form binding" functionality that there are to many limitations trying to work with a programmatically created form. It's very difficult to do.
2. A better solution is to programmatically create a temporary table that has the correct data structure and bind the form to that temp table.

   a. thus the only programmatic part of your form is setting the bindings.  Once that is done, you can rely on the form binding in Access to work easily with your Select, Update, and Append functions.

Answer (score 0):

A standard bound form will do that.

Use the wizard to get started and specify your table as the source.

Comment: I think I need to re-ask this question with more details. This is not a feasible answer for my project. Sorry. Also, your answer does not meet criteria given a generated form.

Comment: It really sounds like you should continue with studying a "Getting Started with Microsoft Access" tutorial. Plenty of these are on-line for the browsing.

Comment: I don't understand why that would help?  So far all my testing suggests that is going to require quite a complicated, unbound form coded in VBA - at the least.  I don't understand how a getting started tutorial will help.  This is a programmatically generated form created at run-time. And I see plenty of people online complaining about the lack of date/calendar tools int he Access UI.  If you have a source to direct me to please do, but the basic guides do not seem to answer this question.

Comment: It's because your question and comments indicate either a lack of the fundamental way Access is supposed to be used and can be used, or - if not the case - you have chosen the wrong tool for your project - and Visual Studio or the like would fit much better.